# Is it possible to cancel a request for a KmlLayer, and load a different layer, before it is actually visible

Tags: google-maps, kml, api

Having asked for a google.maps.KmlLayer, and whilst waiting for it to load, is it possible to cancel the request?

Calling `layer.setMap(null);` seems to causes an error if the layer is not yet visible.

I would like to be able to cancel the request for the layer, then ask for a different layer.

Thanks,

I am using version 3 of the google maps api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, it is not possible, at least via the API. Because it is all asynchronous, once the request is made there is no control over the request/response until the response (the KmlLayer) comes back.